# How to CONSTRUCT a property's transitive closure in SPARQL?

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have an RDF/XML dataset, and it has some relations that can be built into some inference rules. I built my inference rules using `SPARQL` in Jena API. For example, there is a `part_of` relation, if `termA` is `part_of` `termB` , and `termB` is `part_of` `termC`, so we can infer that `termA` is `part_of` `termC`. But I need to make this rule work recursively, so I want all the triples inferred from this rule to be let say the input dataset again then be checked using this rule. To infer new triples I used `construct` in `SPARQL`:

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX go: <http://www.geneontology.org/dtds/go.dtd#>
CONSTRUCT {?termA go:part_of ?termC}
WHERE {
  ?termA go:part_of ?termB .
  ?termB go:part_of ?termC .
  FILTER (?termA != ?termC) .
}
```

from this query above, I can infer only the two level of `part_of` relation, but what I need is the multilevel one. So I tried to make a subquery like this, using the syntax shown in slide 9 of Marianne Shaw's [Ontology Views Update](http://www.slidefinder.net/r/recursion_alternatives/32458696), which in turn *might* be based on Simon Schenk's [*A SPARQL Semantics Based on Datalog*](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-74565-5_14):

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX go: <http://www.geneontology.org/dtds/go.dtd#>
CONSTRUCT {?termA go:part_of ?termC}
FROM <A:/workspace_luna/RDFQuery/src/test.rdf>
FROM NAMED ?g <CONSTRUCT {?termA go:part_of ?termC}
               FROM <A:/workspace_luna/RDFQuery/src/test.rdf>
               WHERE {
                 ?termA go:part_of ?termB .
                 ?termB go:part_of ?termC .
                 FILTER (?termA != ?termC) .
               }>
WHERE {
  ?termA go:part_of ?termB .
  ?termB go:part_of ?termC .
  FILTER (?termA != ?termC) .
}
```

But I obtained an error. I've looked around in many sources and also I tried to apply to my queries, but no one works. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: In general, you can't do recursive stuff like this.  However, in this case, you can use property paths, since (it seems) you're just trying to do a transitive closure.

Comment: You're not showing SPARQL queries in this question;  you're showing code in some programming language (Java perhaps?) that builds a string that contains a SPARQL query .  This isn't a SPARQL query that we could copy and paste.  Please show just the SPARQL query.  Also, in concatenation like this, you should use whitespace and newlines as appropriate.  Otherwise, you end up with the whole query on one line and syntax errors are very hard to find (they'll all be in line 1).  Also, it's easy to do things like `"SELECT ?s" + "WHERE {"` and end up with `SELECT ?sWHERE {` which asks for `?sWHERE`.

Comment: I edited my code by replacing it with your suggestion. Thank you. You are right, here I am trying to do a transitive closure. But I don't understand about property paths. Do you have any reference about it?

Comment: They are clearly described in the SPARQL 1.1 document.  See [9 Property Paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths).  It's kind of like regular expressions.  `?a :partOf+ ?b` matches when `?a` and `?b` are connected by a *path* of :partOf properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problems in your code

> So I tried to make subquery like this: …

I'm not sure what subquery syntax you're trying to use, but it's not legal.  Subqueries are just wrapped in braces. E.g.,

```
select ?s where {
  { select ?x where { ... } }
}
```

The query you've written isn't legal.

> But I obtained an error.

If you don't show us the error, we certainly can't help in fixing it.  I expect that you got a syntax error.  You can validate your query using sparql.org's query validator.  That probably won't help too much in this case, though, because you can only use **select** queries in subqueries.  (It would be very helpful, though, if **construct** queries were supported for subqueries.)

### Transitive closures for construct queries

In general, you can't do arbitrary recursion in SPARQL.  However, in the specific case that you've got, you can use property paths in the pattern to construct the transitive closure of a pattern.  E.g.,

```
construct { ?a :partOf ?b }
where { ?a :partOf+ ?b }
```

This says that if there's a path of non-zero length from **?a** to **?c** using just **:partOf** links, then include a triple **?a :partOf ?b** in the constructed output.

Comment: 1.EXactly, the error is because of syntax error. This subquery syntax I got from an article.

Comment: 2. in the query you made there isn't ?c variable, then i'm confuse about your explanation
3. so if I make my query become like this :
   construct{?a :part_of ?c}
   where { ?a :part_of ?b . ?b :part_of ?c}
   filter (?a != ?c).
which is means that the result will be all triples ?a :part_of ?b , ?b :part_of ?c , and ?a :part_of ?c in one level and multilevel?

Comment: @AriWijayanti 1. Can you link to the article?  It's not legal SPARQL, so I'm suspicious of its quality.  2. Yes, the query does not contain the variable `?c`.  You can rename `?b` to `?c` if you want.  The property path operator `+` means a path of length one or more, so `?a :partOf+ ?b` will match for any `?a` and `?b` where there's a path from `?a` to `?b` made up of `:partOf` properties. E.g., when you have `:a :partOf :x . :x :partOf :y . :y :partOf :b`, you'll get a match.  See [9 Property Paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) in the SPARQL 1.1 definition for details.

Comment: 1. I saw it from a ppt file from this [link](http://www.slidefinder.net/r/recursion_alternatives/32458696) in slide #9
2. I got it and I've tested it in my query and it works, it return the same number of triples as I expected. But if I have two different condition, how am I supposed to do? for example I have my query like this :  'construct{?a :part_of ?c} where {?a :part_of ?b . ?b :is_a ?c} filter(?a != ?c).' I've tried to put '+' after :part_of and :is_a but it returns different number of triples as I expected.

Comment: @AriWijayanti 1. That slide deck is not about SPARQL syntax proper, but about solving a problem in a "SPARQL-like syntax" (see slide 2), and notice that it's based on a syntax apparently described by Simon Schenk (see references).  2. Your original question didn't ask about other conditions, just the transitive properties.  If you have another question, you should post it as a new question, not ask it in the comments.  I'm not sure what you're asking in that comment.  If a is a part of b, and b has a type c, you just do `?a :partOf+ ?b . ?b rdf:type ?c`, unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: But in general, just adding `+` operators to your query isn't going to help anything.  You need to understand the syntax you're using;  programming by trial-and-error in this fashion isn't likely to get you a working result in any reasonable amount of time.

Comment: 1. I got it. 2. You misunderstood my question. anyway I will post another question.

Comment: Should it not be "...path of non-zero length from ?a to ?b using just :partOf links..."? "?c" doesn't feature in the code block.