# How to CONSTRUCT new triples combining two TRANSITIVE CLOSURE in SPARQL?

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have an RDF file with several relations on it. Some of relations have transitive closure. I posted a question before about how to construct a property's transitive closure in Sparql in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231282/how-to-construct-a-propertys-transitive-closure-in-sparql) . Now I am able to construct new triples with property's transitive closure which means extracted all over the path.
For example, there is a `part_of` relation, if `?a` is `part_of` `?b` , and `?b` is `part_of` `?c`, so we can infer that `a` is `part_of` `?c`. Then I made my query like this:

```
construct {?a :part_of ?b} where {?a :part_of+ ?b . filter(?a != ?b) }
```

Then I have another transitive closure. For example, there is an `is_a` relation, if `?a` `is_a` `?b` , and `?b` `is_a` `?c`, so we can infer that `?a` `is_a` `?c`. Then I made my query like this:

```
construct {?a :is_a ?b} where {?a :is_a+ ?b . filter(?a != ?b)}
```

And then I have another condition which is including these two transitive closure:
For example, if `?a` `part_of` `?b` , and `?b` `is_a` `?c`, so we can infer that `?a` `part_of` `?c`. Then could I make my query like this?

```
construct {?a :part_of ?c}
where {
      ?a :part_of+ ?b . 
      ?b :is_a+ ?c .
      filter(?a != ?c)
}
```

Comment: This is much more clearly explained in a new question than in the comments. Thank you! This is very clear and specific!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And then I have another condition which is including these two
>   transitive closure: For example, if ?a part_of ?b , and ?b is_a ?c, so
>   we can infer that ?a part_of ?c. Then could I make my query like this?

To write that alone, it's simply:

```
construct { ?a :part_of ?c }
where {
  ?a :part_of ?b .
  ?b :is_a ?c
}
```

(I'm not sure whether that actually makes sense, though.  After all, ?c is a *type*, not an instance.  My finger is a part of me, and I am a human, but my finger is not a part of human, even though fingers can be parts of things that are humans.)

Since you don't use ?b in the construct part, you can even turn this into a property path:

```
construct { ?a :part_of ?c }
where { ?a :part_of/:is_a ?c }
```

But, none of this handles the transitive part of the problem.  Let's look at that.  You're saying that whenever you can follow a chain of :part_of, there should be a :part_of link, and whenever there's a :part_of followed by a :is_a, there should be a :part_of link.  You can combine those with:

```
construct { ?a :part_of ?c }
where { ?a (:part_of+/:is_a?)+ ?c }
```

The path `(:part_of+/:is_a?)+` means:

- (1) one or more occurrences of:

  - (2) one or more occurrences of :part_of
  - (3) optionally followed by
  - (4) zero or one occurrences of :is_a

If you look at each place where you want to infer a :part_of relationship, you'll see that this pattern matches.

Comment: I got it. But how if I want to check also all the chain of :is_a relation? So if I want to obtain is (1)one or more occurences of : (2)one or more occurences of:part_of (3)optionally followed by(4)one or more occurences of :is_a ; then I just need to change the '?' after :is_a into '+' right?

Comment: I mean 1)one or more occurences of : (2)one or more occurences of:part_of (3)optionally followed by(4)zero or more occurences of :is_a ; then I just need to change the '*' after :is_a into '*' right?

Comment: You just wrote the *same thing twice*;  that's hardly a clarification.  But re-reading it, I think you're on the right track.  It's not a `*` currently after `:is_a`, it's `?`.  Just change it to `+` for "one or more occurrences of".  This is all *very* clearly described in the standard, section [Property Paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths).

Comment: I got it, just tested it, and it works perfectly as I needed. Thank you very much!